# 'dd' command disk copy retains old size

Tags: disk-usage, dd, cloning, lsblk

I recently upgraded my home server and wanted to increase my cloud disk to 2TB from 600gb. After some research I found the dd command which can fully copy a disk, which in my case seemed like a good option since I'm having all data for the docker & databases for my nextcloud intstance on the same disk.

I, successfully, copied and installed the new disk in my computer and all my data is still there intact. My cloud comes up as usual. The only problem I'm seeing now is that the new partition is 600gb instead of 2TB (which I was expecting). In the dashboard my main disk is also listed as 600gb.

I'm guessing that by cloning the disk, I also cloned the disk thinking it's still smaller. When I check with `df -h` I see the disk appear as a 600gb disk on /dev/sde1, but when I use `lsblk` I see sde `- sde1 appear as 1.8T (which i'm expecting).

How can I fix the /dev/sde1 to use the full 1.8TB? The command I used to copy the old disk to the new one is `sudo dd if=/dev/sde1 of=/dev/sdk1 bs=4M status=progress` which is using the right if and to properties.

Thank you in advance :).

Comment: For future reference, `cat` would probably have been significantly faster than how you probably used `dd`

Comment: @roaima: are you sure? `dd` is `cat` for block devices, so it reads data one block (or more) at a time. `dd` is the standard tool to copy disks, wipe disks, etc.

Comment: MrSkeed, is this on a Linux-based system, a Mac, or something else? On a Linux-based system the command you've used will have copied only one partition on the disk rather than cloning the disk itself. On a Mac it may (or may not) have copied an entire disk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, that just means that the filesystem in the partition itself still uses its old size. When resizing a disk on linux, you have to resize it twice, most of the time. First in the partition scheme (eg GPT or MBR) with commands like `parted` or `fdisk`, and then in the file system, with commands like `resize2fs`. The second step largely depends on the used filesystem tho, another command may be necessary if you use something like zfs or btrfs, etc.

Comment: Will this wipe the disk?

Comment: Please check your file-system before using any commands on them. But if it's really an ext file system and you use the command it should work. If you are not sure what a command does or how it works, I'd recommend a wiki or manual. Here's another post using the command, as example: https://serverfault.com/questions/509468/how-to-extend-an-ext4-partition-and-filesystem

Comment: Thanks for your note! I didn't know i had to do it in 2 steps, which i now did and it solved my problem :D

Answer (score 2):

The ‘dd’ process copies every bit in your partition, including the filesystem metadata which describes where it starts and stops.  It also copies every unused bit.  That’s right, you just wasted a bunch of time copying unused sectors.  Also, every bad block (which will cause it to error out instead of continue unless you add a flag to ignore errors).  It will use the same block size and and write it regardless if it is misaligned with the hardware it is on.  All in all, `dd` is a terrible tool to copy the data on a filesystem to another disk.  You should have created a *new* filesystem on the disk, with a partition aligned with the disk geometry, and block size optimized for the kind of disk.  Then you can copy *JUST* the data on the filesystem with tar, rsync, dump/restore etc.